# run pyqt application over a network

Tags: networking, pyqt

I am doing a project. I wanted to know if we can run a pyqt application on a client system with the code of the application in the server, so that the client has no idea abt the program code?

Comment: OF course you can. You "just" need to separate your GUI from you program logic and put a network layout in between.

Comment: @Martin: can u give me some guidance? Pls.

Answer (score 1):

One of many ways to do that is "remote method invocation".
The pyro library is good choice for that approach:
http://packages.python.org/Pyro/index.html

If you want to dig deeper, have a look at socket programming:
http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html